# How to iterate and set values in terraform file through powershell?

Tags: powershell, loops, terraform, iteration

I have a requirement to edit a terraform file and upload it through powerhell. I used Get-Content in powershell to get the values. But the file is coming as an array type. Now I need to change some of the values in the file. How can i achieve this? I used Covert-FromJsom, but it threw errors. Here is the tf content

```
variable "subscription_roles" {
description = "Subscription Roles"
type = list(object({
 name = string
 type = string
 role = string
}))
default = [{
 name = "change1"      
 role = "Owner"
 type = "USER"
 }
]
}


module "subscription_creation" {
source                      = XXXX
version                     = XXXX

}


output "subscription_creation_Subscription_ID" {
value = "${module.subscription_creation.subscriptionID}"
}

output "subscription_creation_Subscription_Name" {
value = "${module.subscription_creation.subscriptionName}"
}

output "subscription_creation_Subscription_Status" {
value = "${module.subscription_creation.subscriptionStatus}"
}
```

Comment: Without any code, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Which terraform file you want to edit?
As you try json I assume this is variable files, is it?

Comment: An example would help here. Convert from JSON fails because TF files in written in HCL, there is no converter I know of. What are the values you need to replace? Can you use tokens? It will make it easier to use replace.
In any case, please provide examples